# How to check for IsPostback in Visual Webpart

Tags: 2010, visual-web-part, postback

I have created visual webpart in SharePoint 2010 which will generate class file for class derived from Webpart and second for UserControl. Now I have TabStrip Control on .ascx markup.
Now I want to add tab in Tabstrip control only once so how can check for Ispostback in userControl ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            if (!this.IsPostBack) {
                AddTab("Drafts");
                AddPageView(radWorkspaceTab.FindTabByText("Drafts"));
                AddTab("Submitted");
            }

        }
```

I have used above code this work but once I add webpart I don't see tabs in design mode and then I refresh page again I can see tabs.

Please advise

Comment: Have you placed a break point in there to confirm that you are definitely not getting into your `if` statement?

Comment: Is it only in the postback where you add the webpart it's missing or whenever it's in design mode? The first is expected with this code

Comment: Thanks Abe for your quick reply.yes i did and i am not getting to code in if statement if i add webpart to webpartzone but once go back to page and refresh i can see tabs i am sure i am missing some lifecycle of events here but dont know

Comment: Thanks Per It is missing when i add webpart and after then if i edit page again i can see tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Use `(!this.Page.IsPostBack)` in Sharepoint